# Domain logon with Linux

Tags: active-directory, domain, winbind

I've set up Samba and winbind, and everything is working fine. I can see all AD users and groups, and corresponding relationships. I've also set up PAM authentication successfully. I have a local user boban, and also AD user with the same username. I've also enabled default domain in winbind directives.

When I reboot host, gui logon dialog appears, and I can log on with user boban either with my local or domain password. But, unlike windows, I can't log on with my domain account right away (I'm getting message about missing logon server, or something in that manner), so I have to wait for couple of seconds. Why? Have domain joining some time delay? In which exactly moment am I joined to domain and which username actually did joining (domain user boban cant add machine to domain)?

When I log on with domain user I can't change password, but when I logon with local user I can, but that is not traversed to AD. How to enable changing password of domain user with simple passwd cmd?